# Need help speeding up my perl program

Tags: perl, hash

Ok, so I am working on a exploit finder to run against change roots, My issue is that when searching for a large number of strings in a large number of files I.E. htdocs, It is taking longer than I would like, I'm positive some advanced perl writers out there can help me speed things up a bit. Here is the part of my program I would like to improve.

```
sub sStringFind {
  if (-B $_ ) {
  }else{
   open FH, '<', $_ ;
   my @lines = <FH>;
   foreach $fstring(@lines) {
    if ($fstring =~ /sendraw|portscan|stunshell|Bruteforce|fakeproc|sub google|sub alltheweb|sub uol|sub bing|sub altavista|sub ask|sub yahoo|virgillio|filestealth|IO::Socket::INET|\/usr\/sbin\/bjork|\/usr\/local\/apache\/bin\/httpd|\/sbin\/syslogd|\/sbin\/klogd|\/usr\/sbin\/acpid|\/usr\/sbin\/cron|\/usr\/sbin\/httpd|irc\.byroe\.net|milw0rm|tcpflooder/) {
     push(@huhFiles, "$_");
   }
  }
 }
}
#End suspicious string find.
find(\&sStringFind, "$cDir/www/htdocs");
for(@huhFiles) {
 print "$_\n";
}
```

Perhaps some hashing? Not sure am not great with perl atm. Any help is appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: ack is... well... betterthangrep.com :-)

Comment: ack would be nice, however there is a large number of machines and various OS's && Kernal versions involved. Thanks though I will probably use the tool in other ways now that you've made me aware of it.

Comment: ack is "better than grep" from interface and feature points of view.  From a performance perspective it will do essentially what he wrote, but with more options, so it's likely to be even slower.

Comment: ack is a single file of Perl, with no external dependencies beyond core Perl.  It is as cross-platform as you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by "hashing" I presume you mean doing a checksum at the file or line level so you don't have to check it again?

The basic problem is, checksum or not, you *still* have to read every line of every file either to scan it or to hash it.  So this doesn't fundamentally change your algorithm, it just pushes around the constants.

If you have a lot of duplicate files, checksuming at the file level might save you a lot of time.  If you don't, it will waste a lot of time.

```
cost = (checksum_cost * num_files) + (regex_cost * lines_per(unique_files))
```

Checksuming at the line level is a toss up between the cost of the regex and the cost of the checksum.  If there's not many duplicate lines, you lose.  If your checksum is too expensive, you lose.  You can write it out like so:

```
cost = (checksum_cost * total_lines) + (regex_cost * (total_lines - duplicate_lines))
```

I'd start by figuring out what percentage of the files and lines are duplicates.  That's as simple as:

```
$line_frequency{ checksum($line) }++
```

and then looking at the percentage where the frequency is `>= 2`.  That percentage is the **maximum** performance increase you will see by checksuming.  If it's 50% you will only ever see an increase of 50%.  That assumes the checksum cost is 0, which it isn't, so you're going to see less.  If the checksum costs half what the regex costs then you'll only see 25%.

This is why I recommend grep.  It will iterate through files and lines faster than Perl can attacking the fundamental problem: you have to read every file and every line.

What you can do is not look at every file every time.  A simple thing to do is remember the last time you scanned and look at the modification time of each file.  It is hasn't changed, and your regex hasn't changed, don't check it again.  A more robust version would be to store the checksums of each file, in case the file was changed by the modification time was altered.  If all your files aren't changing very often, that will see a big win.

```
# Write a timestamp file at the top of the directory you're scanning
sub set_last_scan_time {
    my $dir = shift;

    my $file = "$dir/.last_scan";
    open my $fh, ">", $file or die "Can't open $file for writing: $!";
    print $fh time;

    return
}

# Read the timestamp file
sub get_last_scan_time {
    my $dir = shift;

    my $file = "$dir/.last_scan";

    return 0 unless -e $file;

    open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    my $time = <$fh>;
    chomp $time;

    return $time;
}

use File::Slurp 'read_file';
use File::stat;

my $last_scan_time = get_last_scan_time($dir);

# Place the regex outside the routine just to make things tidier.
my $regex = qr{this|that|blah|...};
my @huhFiles;
sub scan_file {
    # Only scan text files
    return unless -T $_;

    # Don't bother scanning if it hasn't changed
    return if stat($_)->mtime < $last_scan_time;

    push(@huhFiles, $_) if read_file($_) =~ $regex;
}

# Set the scan time to before you start so if anything is edited
# while you're scanning you'll catch it next time.
set_last_scan_time($dir);

find(\&scan_file, $dir);
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Again I am not a pro programmer ;) but moving forward, if you had to re write this small sub routine for speed (using grep)..well could you show me how you would do it with a bit of explanation?

Comment: No worries, man, and na, no duplicates at all probably :/ However I think I may just look at using grep, thanks.

Comment: @noledgeispower There's your code showing how to only scan files which have changed and remember the last time you scanned.  That should give you a big performance win.

Comment: Great answer man, thanks for taking the time, I will def use this on some critical servers. Only issue is I am working with ALOT of servers and "VPS"(lol..) on those servers, could be done, just wouldn't be logical for me to expect the "next guy" to handle it. Nonetheless, you have provided me with the most no-ledge out of anyone else, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything that will cause an obvious performance problem, so you will have to look outside Perl.  Use `grep`.  It should be much faster.

```
open my $grep, "-|", "grep", "-l", "-P", "-I", "-r", $regex, $dir;
my @files = <$grep>;
chomp @files;
```

`-l` will return just filenames that match.  `-P` will use Perl compatible regular expressions.  `-r` will make it recurse through files.  `-I` will ignore binary files.  Make sure your system's grep has all those options.

Comment: Well, I used grep in a previous script combining perl and sh and it was relatively slower due to the fact that perl must generate a shell for every system command it invokes. I am trying to go 100% perl on this one so a hashing solution would be nice :/ I appreciate the help though.

Comment: @noledgeispower If there's lots of files in `$cDir/www/htdocs`, which I surmise there are, you only have to run grep once and the cost of the fork and exec will be swamped by the cost of reading all those documents.  Try it.

Comment: I did try it, and it works, it is what I previously used in an older script. I understand your logic though, and that makes sense, my question is what would be a perl function to replace "grepping" every file in the htdocs.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the other answers, I would suggest performing the regex once on each entire file, not once per line.

```
use File::Slurp 'read_file';
        ...
    if (-B $_ ) {
    }else{
        if ( read_file("$_") =~ /sendraw|portscan|stunshell|Bruteforce|fakeproc|sub google|sub alltheweb|sub uol|sub bing|sub altavista|sub ask|sub yahoo|virgillio|filestealth|IO::Socket::INET|\/usr\/sbin\/bjork|\/usr\/local\/apache\/bin\/httpd|\/sbin\/syslogd|\/sbin\/klogd|\/usr\/sbin\/acpid|\/usr\/sbin\/cron|\/usr\/sbin\/httpd|irc\.byroe\.net|milw0rm|tcpflooder/) {
            push(@huhFiles, $_);
        }
    }
```

Make sure you are using at least perl5.10.1.

Comment: I like the answer man, however I am not, and unfortunately cannot use the suggested version of perl, there is a large number of machines involved with various OS's and kernal versions, thanks though.

Comment: @noledgeispower: your regex will be much much slower before 5.10

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of things I would do to improve performance.

First, you should be precompiling your regex. In general, I do it like this:
my @items=qw(foo bar baz);             #usually I pull this from a config file
my $regex='^' . join "|", @items . '$'; #as an example. I do a lot of capturing, too.
$regex=qr($regex)i;

Second, as mentioned, you should be reading the files a line at a time. Most performance from what I've seen is running out of ram, not cpu.

Third, If you are running out of one cpu and have a lot of files to work, split the app into caller and receivers using fork(), so that you can process multiple files at one time using more than  one cpu. You could write to a common file, and when done, parse that.

Finally, watch your memory usage -- a lot of times, a file append lets you keep what is in memory a lot smaller.

I have to process large data dumps using 5.8 and 5.10, and this works for me.

Comment: I am on 5.6 and 5.8 mix, upgrading is not a tomorrow option, ya it would be memory more than cpu, I am no experienced programmer, only been working with perl for about 3 weeks lol, but I understand your concept, could you give me a snippet in relation to my regex that I could plug in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but when you open the `<FH>` you're reading the entire file into a perl array (`@lines`) all at once.  You might get better performance by opening the file, and reading it line by line, rather than loading the entire file into memory before processing it.  However, if your files are small, your current method might actually be faster...

See this page for an example:  http://www.perlfect.com/articles/perlfile.shtml

It might look something like this (note the scalar `$line` variable - not an array):

```
open FH, '<' $_;

while ($line = <FH>)
{
    # do something with line
}

close FH;
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, your script reads the entire contents of each file into @lines, then scans every line. That suggests two improvements: Reading a line at a time, and stopping as soon as a line matches.

Some additional improvements: The `if (-B $_) {} else { ... }` is odd - if you only want to process text files, use the `-T` test. You should **always** check the return value of open(). And there's a useless use of quotes in your `push()`. Taken all together:

```
sub sStringFind {
    if (-T $_) {
        # Always - yes, ALWAYS check for failure on open()
        open(my $fh, '<', $_) or die "Could not open $_: $!";

        while (my $fstring = <$fh>) {
            if ($fstring =~ /sendraw|portscan|stunshell|Bruteforce|fakeproc|sub google|sub alltheweb|sub uol|sub bing|sub altavista|sub ask|sub yahoo|virgillio|filestealth|IO::Socket::INET|\/usr\/sbin\/bjork|\/usr\/local\/apache\/bin\/httpd \/sbin\/syslogd|\/sbin\/klogd|\/usr\/sbin\/acpid|\/usr\/sbin\/cron|\/usr\/sbin\/httpd|irc\.byro \.net|milw0rm|tcpflooder/) {
                push(@huhFiles, $_);
                last; # No need to keep checking once this file's been flagged
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting I am going to try this now, but as far as returning errors..Not trying to do that because the amount of files here could be 100 - ...a lot haha, thanks though some good insight on this response I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, I am running into the same issue now with both our methods(I intend to go with yours). The program is being killed with SIGTERM. Any suggestions on how to prevent such?

Comment: @noledgeispower Are you on Dreamhost?

Comment: Are you running this on your server? I suspect the admins may have set up a limit that your script is bumping into. If it's only 100 files, just download them and run the scan on your development machine. You should have a local copy for backup purposes anyway...

Comment: lol, not dreamhost :). And I am sure that no admins have set limits. Notice that says could be a 100..alot, I am root.

Comment: Oh, and as far as error checking goes, **checking** for errors does not necessarily mean `die()`ing. If you want to continue to the next file (which I can understand), simply use `warn()` instead. The important part is getting in the habit of checking, not how you handle an error if you find one.

Comment: A hundred files is not a lot. I used to update & publish 1400 .html pages every week. :-)

Comment: again.. 100..alot, let me be more specific, could be 100, could be oh I dunno 200,000 give or take.

Comment: Don't get me wrong though, your code snippet has given me some insight into doing things differently in some situations, thanks man.

Comment: Then find out what's sending that SIGTERM. You say the admin (you, apparently) didn't set a limit, but that signal ain't sending itself - it's almost certainly a watchdog that kills processes that have run for too long.

Comment: If you didn't set that up explicitly, it was probably included in the initial setup, whether that was from a hosting provider or a *nix distribution.

Comment: I figure the same, dont think its a time ran thing though, seems to be a resource issue. Would you say your method is faster than using grep or egrep?

Comment: I'd say there are too many variables to do more than guess. Try 'em both and see, is the only way to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something else.

If you're assembling you regexp from a list of search terms. Then [Regexp::Assemble::Compressed](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aAssemble%3a%3aCompressed) can be used to fold your search terms into a shorter regular expression:

```
use Regexp::Assemble::Compressed;

my @terms = qw(sendraw portscan stunshell Bruteforce fakeproc sub google sub alltheweb sub uol sub bing sub altavista sub ask sub yahoo virgillio filestealth IO::Socket::INET /usr/sbin/bjork /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd /sbin/syslogd /sbin/klogd /usr/sbin/acpid /usr/sbin/cron /usr/sbin/httpd irc.byroe.net milw0rm tcpflooder);

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble::Compressed->new;
$ra->add("\Q${_}\E") for @terms;
my $re = $ra->re;
print $re."\n";

print "matched" if 'blah blah yahoo' =~ m{$re};
```

This produces:

```
(?-xism:(?:\/(?:usr\/(?:sbin\/(?:(?:acpi|http)d|bjork|cron)|local\/apache\/bin\/httpd)|sbin\/(?:sys|k)logd)|a(?:l(?:ltheweb|tavista)|sk)|f(?:ilestealth|akeproc)|s(?:tunshell|endraw|ub)|(?:Bruteforc|googl)e|(?:virgilli|yaho)o|IO::Socket::INET|irc\.byroe\.net|tcpflooder|portscan|milw0rm|bing|uol))
matched
```

This may be of benefit for very long lists of search terms, particularly for Perl pre 5.10.

Comment: Just learned a thing or two from this one man, thanks, I have never used the mod, awesome answer though I will be using this.

Answer (score 0):

Just working from your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# it looks awesome to use strict
use strict;
# using warnings is beyond awesome
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $keywords = qr[sendraw|portscan|stunshell|Bruteforce|fakeproc|sub google|sub alltheweb|sub uol|sub bing|sub altavista|sub ask|sub yahoo|virgillio|filestealth|IO::Socket::INET|\/usr\/sbin\/bjork|\/usr\/local\/apache\/bin\/httpd|\/sbin\/syslogd|\/sbin\/klogd|\/usr\/sbin\/acpid|\/usr\/sbin\/cron|\/usr\/sbin\/httpd|irc\.byroe\.net|milw0rm|tcpflooder];

my @huhfiles;

find sub {
        return unless -f;
        my $file = $File::Find::name;

        open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$!\n";
        local $/ = undef;
        my $contents = <$fh>;
        # modern Perl handles this but it's a good practice
        # to close the file handle after usage
        close $fh;

        if ($contents =~ $keywords) {
                push @huhfiles, $file;
        }
}, "$cDir/www/htdocs";

if (@huhfiles) {
        print join "\n", @huhfiles;
} else {
        print "No vulnerable files found\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't read all the of the lines at once.  Read one line at a time, and then when you find a match in the file, break out of the loop and stop reading from that file.

Also, don't interpolate when you don't need to.  Instead of

```
push(@huhFiles, "$_");
```

do

```
push(@huhFiles, $_);
```

This won't be a speed issue, but it's better coding style.